# How do I install/use SQL Developer from inside of VS Code?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle

I want to work with my Oracle Database, run queries, create tables, run sql scripts, etc, but from VS Code.

How do I do that, without creating an Oracle account, or installing anything like an Oracle Client, .NET, or Java?

*Disclaimer: I work for Oracle.*

Comment: You should add a disclaimer to your question that you are an Oracle employee. Apart from that, you appear to be trying to seed StackOverflow with an (off-topic) question to promote your product.

Comment: Done, also the topic if sql developer, i get asked ALL the time how to get started from people that run into java, .net, oracle client conflicts. You'e seen those questions here.

Answer (score 6):

Simply search for ['sql-developer' in the Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Oracle.sql-developer), and hit 'Install'

[image]

There's no requirement for .NET, Java, or Oracle Homes/Clients/Drivers.

You'll get both a GUI for working with your Oracle Databases as well as an integrated CLI via Oracle SQLcl.